# How to update, not replace, data in one workbook from another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook called StockList, containing a list of items, their stock count and their allocation count.

I have multiple 'jobs', each with its own Excel workbook for keeping data and producing documents etc.

Each job's workbook will have the items needed and how many of those items.

I want to have an 'allocation' and 'close' tool for each job's workbook, where the items in that job's workbook get added to the allocation cell for that item in the StockList.

Here is the desired effect,

---

**ExampleJobWorkbook**

Item    QTY
ItemA    4
ItemB    4
ItemC    5
ItemD    5

(ALLOCATE BUTTON)
(CLOSE BUTTON)

---

**StockList**

Item   Qty  Allocated
ItemA  50   0
ItemB  50   4
ItemC  50   4
ItemD  50   0

When Allocate is clicked in the Job workbook above, the Stocklist becomes

Item   Qty  Allocated
ItemA  50   4
ItemB  50   8
ItemC  50   9
ItemD  50   5

At some point after allocation the job will be closed with the close button, then the StockList reads

Item   Qty  Allocated
ItemA  46   0
ItemB  46   4
ItemC  45   4
ItemD  45   0

I have made activex buttons and written scripts to select the data I need and then open the StockList. I had hoped to use the += operator below but it won't compile.

```
Workbooks("StockList.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value += itemA
```

I can't just change the value as it needs to ADD to the value already on the stocklist (multiple jobs at once).

I'm also looking for a way to find the specific items required by a job in the StockList and then updating their cells accordingly. Right now I am just mapping each item in the job workbook to the stocklist, but there are many items in the stocklist and not all are used by a job!

Comment: += doesn't exist in VBA need to do something like this: `Workbooks("StockList.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = Workbooks("StockList.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value + itemA`

Comment: Please do not edit your question with the answer. If you would like to leave the full solution, please write an answer to your own question. And be very clear that you are copying someone's answer into yours.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Marco Getrost but you could make your code easier by using the Workbook, Worksheet and Range data types :

```vb
Dim myWorkbook as Workbook
Dim mySheet as Worksheet
Dim myCell as Range
' Get a workbook - 
Set myWorkbook = Workbooks("StockList.xlsx")
' Get a worksheet 
Set mySheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' Both lines below are equivalent
Set myCell = mySheet.Cells(1, 3)
Set myCell = mySheet.Range("C1")
' Increase the value of your cell
myCell.Value = myCell.Value + itemA
```

Of course this is useful if you reuse these variables in your code. I am not saying here that typing 10 lines is easier than 1 :)

Comment: Thank you this looks very helpful! I don't have time to try it now but will get back to you soon. With this code do you not have to explicitly open the StockList.xlsx with Workbooks.Open as you are editing the file?

Comment: Yes you can : ```Set wbStockList = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\To\My\File\StockList.xlsx")```

Comment: Looks like your suggestion would work perfectly, but `mySheet.Range("C1").Value = mySheet.Range("C1").Value + itemA` fails, with a type mismatch error. The issue is itemA is an integer but C1 is a boolean. It contains `0`, which is formatted as a number but the code keeps seeing it as a boolean `True`. I could add code to store it and convert it into 0 but I'd have to do that MANY times with many items. Can I not tell it the 0 is a number...

Comment: Weird : I thought to be a boolean your cell should contain the string value ```TRUE``` or ```FALSE``` (actually it depends on your Office language, mine is French so the key values are ```VRAI``` and ```FAUX```). And VBA can add a boolean and an integer without cast error. Are you sure C1 is not the cell that contains your column title "Allocated" ?

Comment: OKay that was the issue, but just as a curious side note, I was printing the variables to a msgbox in the debug process and weirdly enough all my column headers (Namely 'Item', 'Stock', 'Allocated' and 'Free') had values 'True' in the script. I might have a few other queries in bound but thank you a lot for your help.